# Debian 11 not booting - grub command line is shown

Tags: linux, debian, dual-boot, grub

I installed Debian 11 on an external hard drive connected to my iMac. This isn't because I want a dual-boot, the internal SSD is only 120GB, while the external one is much larger. The install was completed successfully and I pressed continue to boot into Debian after removing the installer drive. Instead of booting into Debian, it booted into grub. I have no knowledge of Linux or grub, so this is all foreign to me. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/838559) and followed the steps (using Debian instead of Ubuntu) but it still boots into grub. I tried just using the `boot` command but it says the kernel needs to be loaded first. I was able to find the partition that contains the EFI in grub but not the root folder. Anything I found online has not helped and my issue seems to be different than most so this is not a duplicate. I even tried re-installing Debian on the external drive, again it said successfully installed, but the same issue occurs. At this point, I have no idea what to try. Below is what pops up super quick, when booting, right before an empty command line...

```
APFSStart: 1456 : Mounting with apfs_efi_osx-748.77.10
efi_fusion pairing:635: Container caa44c9-13bf-4a9d-69b7-de08b79bfef1
efi_fusion_pairing:640: fusion uuid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
efi_container_create:929: Volume attached is internal
nx_kernel_mount: 1359: : checkpoint search: largest xid 7258996. best xid 7258996
 @ 211
er_state_obj_get_for _recovery:3848: No ER state object for volume Preboot - rolling is not happening, nothing to recover.
er_state_obj_get_for _recovery:3848: No ER state object for volume Hard Disc - rolling is not happening, nothing to recover.
er_state obj_get_for _recovery:3848: No ER state object for volume Recovery - rolling is not happening, nothing to recover.
er_state_obj_get_for _recovery:3848: No ER state object for volume UM - rolling is not happening, nothing to recover.
Welcome to GRUB!
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30650 from 'hd0'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30a80 from 'hd0'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30b50 from 'hd1'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30a80 from 'hd1'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30b50 from 'hd2'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30a80 from 'hd2'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30b50 from 'hd3'.
error: failure reading sector Oxdf30a80 from 'hd3'.
error: no such device: a007eBeB-0317-431a-adcf-5d0acb505dcf.
```

Questions specifically about the `failure reading sector` errors say that means a failing drive but both the internal and external drives are fine. I’m not sure if these errors are a part of the problem but it’s worth mentioning.

Comment: How are you so sure about your drives?

Comment: The internal SSD loads macOS without any issues. The external HDD used to store other data until a few days ago when I decided to use Debian. So, as far as I know, the drives are good, but I don’t know the signs of a failing drive or how to diagnose it. I’m not even sure what drives `hd0-hd3` are but I assume one of them is the external drive because `(hd6,gpt1)` is where I found the EFI so hd6 is probably the internal drive. It’s worth mentioning that the external drive is 4TB so maybe it’s too large but I don’t think that’s the issue.

Comment: Live boot e.g. Linux Mint, disable sleep, install one small utility `pv`. Then I would run `sudo -i` and then `pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/null` where sdX is your external drive (unmounted). Best to run it over night and in the morning look at `sudo dmesg -T` looking through it for red lines. I deal with dying HDDs / SSDs, this is one way to do a **quick** look, there are better tools, but I think you want it fast at the moment. Cheers

Comment: I’m currently running pv like you recommended but after mounting the external drive in macOS and looking at the contents everything seems right and I still don’t think it’s failing. Also, when I run the ’ls’ command in grub, there is 6 drives yet I only have one internal and one external. I’m not counting partitions, it literally shows ’hd0’-’hd6’ and I have no idea why.